# Getting a "no match for 'operator>>' " error in my C++ code

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int T,n ;
    long int x,y,z,i,j;
    cin >> T >> endl ;
    for(j=1;j<=T;j++) {   
        cin >> n >> endl ;
        if((T>=1&&T<100000)&&(n>=1&&n<=8000000)){
            for(x=1;x<=8000000;x++)
                for(y=1;y<=8000000;y++){
                    for(z=1;z<=8000000;z++){
                        if(((y-x)==(z-y))&&((x*x)-(y*y)-(z*z)==n))
                            i++ ;
                        else continue; 
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is:

> no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream}' and '')

I get this error whenever my code receives input.

Comment: try to change `cin >> T >> endl;` to `cin >> T;`

Comment: Please improve the formatting. A space here and there would not go a miss in expressions. Then fix the indentation

Comment: Please properly indent your code. Your syntax errors will be seen much faster!

Comment: Also, a good title tries to describe the problem, not only "whine" about what you're not able to do. For example, "compiler error when using `cin >>`"  would be much, much better

Answer (score 5):

You don't `cin >>` something to `endl`. That doesn't make sense – `endl` is a construct to give things like `cout` the instruction to do whatever is right to end a line on your specific  platform, not something you can save input to.

Comment: Well, it would make sense if one just provided that overload of `>>`. I think that's a good idea. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't think it would be. The type of `endl` is an `ostream`, and you don't want to overload the `>>` for `ostream` right hand arguments, since that will break other stuff, too. Well, depends on what you do.

Comment: No, `endl<Char_type>` is a function. The only problem is to react to only that particular function of that type. But I don't think there are any other output manipulators that could be of interest for input?

Comment: `basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl(basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os)` gives you a `basic_ostream`. And `istream>>ostream` is something that I wouldn't want to implement with anything that doesn't actually build a pipe between these two.

Comment: Apparently there's something you don't understand here. But I can't decide whether it is the notion of manipulators, or how a manipulator can be used for both input and output, and it's a bit too much to explain anyway. Here's an [example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b399ec721f8cfa9e).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf right, with the possibility to get the type via decltype combined with a narrow argument type, this makes sense.